# Applying a stand-alone script to any google form that will be created

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, google-apps-script-addon

So my issue is that I'm trying to make an "approval system" for people applying to my organization. The way I have it now is, whenever someone fills out the application (a google form), a separate google form is then automatically created and sent to my coworker asking "Is this applicant accepted?". What I want is all of the data stored from their application to be added to a google sheet of an active roster ONLY if my coworker clicks "yes the applicant is accepted". I do not want their info saved if they are not approved.

So essentially, is there a way to apply a generic script to a google form that hasn't been made yet (since the approval form is made only after the applicant fills out the application).

Also sorry if this is a really stupid question, I've just now started to learn how Google Scripts works.

Thank you!

Comment: A stand alone script has no linkage to a form.  onSubmitTriggers are only connected to Forms or Spreadsheets.  So how with the stand alone script be aware of the form submission.

Answer (score 2):

So I'm not 100% certain if this will suit your needs, but here is something that might accomplish the goal of setting up an approval system:

1. A google form where potential applicants fill in their information. I will refer to it as the applicant form from here on.
2. A spreadsheet associated with the applicant form that accepts all relevant applicant data when the applicant form is submitted. I will refer to it as the potential applicant spreadsheet from here on.
3. A second spreadsheet where only verified applicants are placed. I will refer to it as the verified applicants spreadsheet.

And here is how you could have all of those pieces work together:

1. The applicant form would dump its data directly into the potential applicant spreadsheet each time it is submitted. That script could also send out a nicely-formatted email to your coworker if needed.
2. The potential applicant spreadsheet would be shared with your coworker and would have a simple checkbox-type interface to allow them to approve or disapprove each applicant or multiple applicants at once.
3. The potential applicant spreadsheet would have a button and associated script that would check for newly approved applicants and then add them to the verified applicants spreadsheet.

I haven't included any code in this answer as it would depend a lot on what exactly you want it to do. However, as a Google Apps Script tutor, (see tutoringbyroger.com), I know the above setup is possible. If you are wondering how to run a script easily from a button in a google sheet, see [this info](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets)! in the documentation that covers that.

Anyhow, I hope that gives you some idea of where to start.

Answer (score 0):

The way to apply the same standalone script to any form is by publishing it as an [editor add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/building-editor-addons), more specifically as a form add-on.